# Asp.Net MVC Identity and Our Database single context for whole application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used MVC Identity for user login and registration purposes....but i needed to add additional database table also like this are completly unrelated with Identity database table...in my application i use code first.....i have made class for this.....but i want a single context in whole application

```
public DbSet<Dept> Dept{ get; set; }
public DbSet<Course> Course{ get; set; }
public DbSet<Etc> Etc{ get; set; }
```

As asp.net identity have ApplicationDBContext and i was using other database context which is defined by this

```
public class MainContext : DbContext
```

So what i want is i should be able to create my database table and Identity table when database changes detected and i am creating user and role when application starts at ApplicationDbInitializer which is working ok.
Now i want just a single context for whole application....
Things i have tried or think is inherit Maincontext with ApplicationDbContext

But still i can see 2 context and Other thing is i can inherit from IdentityDbContext but still there  will be 2 context.

Show me simple example if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: If you do want a single DbContext (and it may be helpful to explain why if you have a strong business need for this), you should add your DbSet collections to the Identity ApplicationDbContext rather than create an additional DbContext class.

Comment: Actually there is not strong requirements but i think if we not use same context then there will be problem when we needed to use Identity tables data....Also might be problem when initializing is done...what you say,,, according to your solution just needed add dbset collection to ApplicationDbContext Right ?